# Debugging Core Data managed objects with predicates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

My application has the data models a little bit complicated. I need to debug a fetch request with different predicates.

Is there any fast way to see different results for different predicates? I am tired with changing only one predicate and I have to start again my navigation application with nearly 10 steps before.

An example of these predicates that I would like to see the results:

```
item = %@
item = %@ AND quantity = %@
item = %@ OR (startdate >= %@ AND enddate <= %@)
etc...
```

As using Core Data, I can not see the database with its' values to do some SELECTs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add logic in your code to change the predicate and fetch again (maybe add a temporary button to trigger this and cycle through your various predicates).

You may also be interested in viewing the data in your SQLite file. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data/2268118#2268118) to [How view data stored in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

Comment: oops, these are two commercial products :D Thanks anyway for your suggestions ;)

Comment: Can I assume that you will be giving all of the software that you develop away for free?

Comment: What I mean is you have to convince your boss to spend the money to buy a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is any help, but if you want to quickly see the return results, go into gcc command line and write

```
po <name of array with results>
```

so if the array is items

```
po items
```

Will give all the returned results printed nicely in the console

Comment: but I can not dynamically change the Predicate to test the new one, right?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can however build the manipulation in your app, say using a text field to enter the predicate format string.

Answer (score -1):

To view your data inside of SQLite for free, just get FireFox. Then install SQLite Manager.

Cheers.

-RoLYroLLs

http://iphone.rolyrolls.com