# Display iPhone Core Data DB outside of app

Tags: sql, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Is there any way to display the content of an SQLite-Database (Created with core data) outside of your app?

Any DB-manager that can display it's data or any way of viewing the raw data in Xcode?

//OC

Comment: possible duplicate of [How view data stored in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, and from the command line I haven't been able to see all I wanted to see, but I lack the experience of DB interaction to rule that option out.

BUT, I've seen "Dr. Brad Larson" in a great tutorial about Core Data use an application call: "Base" that is available on the Mac AppStore. ( http://menial.co.uk/software/base/ )

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Q/A: [How view data stored in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

I second the recommendation of [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/)