# How to open CoreData database file to see saved values

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Right now i am using coredata to save my data. 
Its all working fine but now i changed the logic to save values to the database. So i need to compare that the after logic change same values are getting saved in tables. So I need to compare tables.

I went through many links like
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239634/how-can-i-check-what-is-stored-in-my-core-data-database)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

all the links shows that the database file that coredata create is of .sqlite extension. But the files create at that location are "persistentStore, persistentStore-shm, persistentStore-wal" as show in screenshot.

[image: Image of database file]

How should i suppose to open these files to see the saved data in tables.
Thanks in advance

```
 - (void)setupDatabase:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler
{

    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDataModel"];

    self.db = [[CWUIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    self.db.persistentStoreOptions = options;

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.db.fileURL path]])
    {
        [self.db saveToURL:self.db.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            self.dataManager.db = self.db;
            completionHandler(success);
        }];
    } else if (self.db.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [self.db openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            self.dataManager.db = self.db;
            completionHandler(success);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `persistentStoreCoordinator`?

Comment: i am just using this method to setup the database

Comment: Can you replace `url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDataModel"];
` into `url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDataModel.sqlite"];`. Delete app and run again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql file is the one without extension. The other 2 files are for journaling mode.

This has already been explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store). Apple changed the default journaling mode to WAL on iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

In `setupDatabase()` method replace the following line

```
 url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDataModel"]
```

with

```
 url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainDataModel.sqlite"]
```

You have to create the persistent store type as `Sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands on terminal and open your`persistentStore` in sqlite manager. These commands will merge the WAL file into the main sqlite file

```
$ sqlite3 persistentStore
sqlite> PRAGMA wal_checkpoint;

Press control + d
```

These steps are already covered in the answer of the above link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43406516/468724