# Retrieve Core Data DB data from iPhone using swift 3.0

Tags: iphone, core-data, swift3, ios11

How can I retrieve data from a core data DB from my iOS device (iOS 11, Xcode version 9.2) into my system. i am using Swift 3.0 code. I have tried these two links already, but the data doesn't show up , only the tables show up:

[How can I check what is stored in my Core Data Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239634/how-can-i-check-what-is-stored-in-my-core-data-database)

[How view data stored in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Did you copy the SQLite journal files too?

Comment: yes I added them all together , but the DBSqlite gave error. So I merged them into a single file using terminal and then it was empty.