# I can't find ios simulator files

Tags: ios

I need to look my application's database file.I found this question:

[How view data stored in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

In answer he said:

> Your app will be folder inside (~ is your home directory):
>   ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/

I opened the `Application Support` folder but there is no `iPhone Simulator` folder inside this folder.

What should I do ? Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Edit:I am using xCode 6 and Yosemite.

Comment: What is the version of the xcode you are using? also are you using yosemite? that answer seems old location for he simulator files are changed I believe

Comment: Xcode 6 and Yosemite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Document Directory Path of iOS 8 Beta Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198840/document-directory-path-of-ios-8-beta-simulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone Simulator files have moved and can be a bit of a pain to find now. Each simulated device has a folder in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices. You can root around in there until you find the simulator you're looking for. I wrote a tool to help locate the sandbox for each simulated device on which you've installed an app, but it's not perfect. You can find it here: https://github.com/somegeekintn/SimDirs

There is also an app called SimPholders2 that may be able to help you with this problem - http://simpholders.com/

Comment: Thank you,I found the folder.But do you know why there is no data folder ? http://prntscr.com/6lbjg5

Answer (score 2):

for me it it is  `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7E8D457-BFAB-43DA-8B0C-D9010BBB1D88/data/Containers/Data/Application/6B7DC6FA-2379-468C-A74B-60910A1CDCD1/Documents`

device id and application id will be different for you though. this would give you documents directory for your app.

```
NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSLog (@"documentsDirectory %@",documentsDirectory);
```

Answer (score 2):

OK The whole Problem lies in the fact that you need to open the Finder >> View >> Show View Options  and then click to turn on Library.

Why would someone hide this so deep and obscurely?

Comment: I'd love to know who'e actually in charge of these pathetic UI decisions. They should be shot!

Comment: @amergin They must be hoping mac to be used only by management people for excel sheets and notepad at max.. :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Core Data Lab** to automatically find and view the database files of any Core Data app running in the simulator.

Info page: https://betamagic.nl/products/coredatalab.html

Free 14-trial: https://betamagic.nl/downloads/Core%20Data%20Lab%20Trial.zip

*Diclaimer: I'm the creator of this tool.*