# Viewer/Query Analyzer for SQLite databases

Tags: database, sqlite

I've been using SQLite databases for development for a while now and I thought it would be useful to just view the contents of the generated db file.  Are there any good tools out there for viewing SQLite db files and/or tools for running queries against them?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are a few free tools:

- [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) (Firefox plugin)
- [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)
- [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index)
- [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

I prefer SQLite Administrator, and occasionally use the Firefox version.  There are other commercial options too.

Answer (score 7):

[SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

**SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager**

It's free and it has a **visual query builder** just like professional database management tools.
[image: Visual query builder]

Its list of features is:

- Encryption Method compatible with wxSQLite3 (AES-128 bits) and
  SQLite3 ADO.NET Provider (RSA-MS Crypt)
- Syntax Highlight
- Hex Viewer
- Dump database to SQL file format
- Unicode Support
- Blob/Image viewer
- Built-in FTS3 Extension
- Built-in LUA Programming Language
- Encrypted database support
- Export recordset into excel, csv, xml and html format
- Import data from MS Access, MS SQL server, MySQL and dBase III
- Includes SQLite2010 Pro ODBC Driver
- Includes Additional sqlite3 function (`compress`, `decompress`, `crc32`,
  `md5`, `lua_exec`, etc)
- Transactions supported
- Visual Query Builder
- Includes the user-contributed extension-functions from
  http://www.sqlite.org/contrib.

[Download it from its homepage](http://osenxpsuite.net/download.htm) (just scroll down to *Freeware* section)

Answer (score 1):

[Sqliteman](http://sqliteman.com/) - I was looking for something light and available on Fedora repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently introduced to [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) . I might not have as many features as some of those above (though I haven't fully explored it yet). But it's pretty sweet, for a simple query interface that works.
Plus you can practice your LINQ with it too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another database viewer nobody has mentioned: [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)