# iOS - a way to browse sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Core Data browsing tool out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609683/is-there-a-good-core-data-browsing-tool-out-there)

Is there a way to browse an sqlite database on iOS?

I use CoreData to store entities in one of my applications, and I would like to browse the tables to be sure that the database saves what I want. I'm thinking about a kind of database viewer.

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609683/is-there-a-good-core-data-browsing-tool-out-there

Comment: You can also have a look on the tools posted here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624573/viewer-query-analyzer-for-sqlite-databases

Comment: Core Data Editor seems to be good to browse device database, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your application inside the simulator on your Mac, you can get to your files inside

`/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/version/appid/Documents`

Just open your database there with any tool like Base or SQLiteManager.

**UPDATE:**

Since IOS 8 they put it in a different folder:

`Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/(numbers and letters)/data/Containers/Data/Application/(numbers and letters)/Documents/`

Comment: Thank you I will use this solution

Comment: Also, check out SimPholders for quick access to your app's folders when using the simulator.

Comment: Hello sir there is not file in my document directory i don;t know why?

Comment: Either you have no created a file, or the file is someplace else. Just create a file called xxx.sql and then use terminal and do 'find . -name xxx.sql'

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) addon for Firefox and it worked well for SQLite databases.