# Adding objects to Core Data graphically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am pretty new to using Core Data, so I'd like to ask how I graphically add items to the database I am making. With graphically I mean like in navicat I can edit things with editor.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by 'graphically'. There is no drag & drop entity management at runtime of your application 'out of the box', if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is a object oriented framework that provides object persistence, not a visual database editor. Xcode contains a visual tool for creating and editing Core Data models, which are similar to database schemas, but there's no visual facility for managing or manipulating the data that a model describes. It can take a little while to understand Core Data; I'd suggest starting with [Apple's Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://tinyurl.com/5tnmt3z).

Comment: My app contains a lot of items which it has to display and they will be pre populated, do you still recommend core data or something else?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend against Core Data based on the prepopulated data requirement -- Core Data can work fine for that. However, you'll need to come up with a way to enter the data. You might look for a third party tool (like one suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1609683/643383) or just write your own -- it doesn't have to be fancy or complicated if you're just creating a little MacOS X application for your own use.

Answer (score 1):

May be am not clear with the term graphically. When you start creating your model using Core data, you need to choose a data model from project resources (of type .xcdatamodel) and when you select this,it wil open a model editor for you. you can create as many entities, related attributes and establish relationships. Hope this will help you.

~Manoj.

Comment: I mean like if I have made an entity called item, how I add more items to my database?

Comment: Your application does that by calling appropriate methods in the Core Data API. If you want to pre-populate a data store to ship with your app, it's a simple matter to write a little utility program to do that.

Comment: So can I just write a mac app that does it and copy the database file from the folder somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to instantiate a new entity and add it to your data store, you'll use the method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` on `NSEntityDescription` to create a new instance of your entity and insert it into your context. You have to call `saveChanges` on the context to persist that new entity to your data store. Core Data is a really powerful framework, but it isn't something most developers can just start using blindly. Read the [Core Data guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), download some of the sample code, and you'll be rocking in no time.