# How to Open data(saved using core data model) saved in my in pad

Tags: ios, core-data

Im new to core data, Created one model and saved some data in my simulator and opened the .sqlite folder  which will contain my data.

Now i done the same thing in my iPad with different data

1. How to see that .Sqlite file,  where its stored… in iPad
2. Can I copy Same data in another iPad, I mean with out entering all data again ….

Thanks …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get your app's container when you attach you device to Xcode.

Windows->Devices->Your App->Click the small setting button->Select download container.

[image]

Show the content of your appdata you saved, you will see the .sqlite file in the folder.

In terms of browsing the data, you have several choices.
Here is a discussion about good tool for browsing core data.
[Is there a good Core Data browsing tool out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609683/is-there-a-good-core-data-browsing-tool-out-there)
In this case I use DB Browser, it works fine.

2. Could you explain more why you want to do that?

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Im developing POS application, I have 1000's of items to store in app, So after saving  in one iPad, want to shift the same to the other devices..

Comment: Hi Krishna
Did you try to replace the container? I guess it may not work.
I don't have chance to do that at this moment, not sure whether is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by storing your data files in "Documents" folder, whose path is:

```
- (NSString *)pathToDocumentFolder
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    if( [paths count] < 1 )
        return nil;

    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```